# ACCESS - calculating prices

Tags: ms-access

I have one table in my access DB which contains a list of all devices that has been sold to our customer. We have only one customer and only one type of device. The table contains details like name, serial, warranty detail of device. Now we need to calculate the price for invoice purpose. The thing is that the price should be calculated depending on amount of sold devices and also we don't want to hard code the price instead we would like to use a separate table whit different category of prices and calculating the price based on this table, because of the prices changing frequently and so we should modify the price value only in one table.

We have 3 category of price : if customer bought 100 device then the unit price is 15$ else if 200 devices the unit price would be 10$ else if 300 then price for unit would be 5$. So based on these rules we will need to calculate the price.

So I'm looking for the right approach that would be for this problem.

Comment: Well Gustavo one thing is sure is that we were not in the same school. Generally we are not selling devices in school. Your comment is absolutely useless and not constructive. Just try to read  until the end of my question, I'm looking for the "right approach" for this problem and defiantly not that someone can give me a complete solution. You know approach like "you will need to use a calculated fields" or "create a second table with category table and join them"... More details on verb "approach"  - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/approach

Comment: I understand that, but please have in mind that SO is for code helping, not opinions. There is no _right_ nor _wrong_ method to approach this; it depends on many factors of which most are known only by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question and is impossible to definitively answer without more information about the architecture of the database.

There are 3 different ways I usually perform a calculation inside my Access databases.

1. perform a calculation inside a query. For simple things.
2. perform a calculation inside a module function, that is called by a query. For complicated things.
3. perform a calculation inside a module vba subroutine, that is called by a button OnClick Event. For extremely complicated things.

Comment: it is exactly what I was looking for, suggestions. I will look further with provided ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cross join as long as you have a range wide enough to account for all possibilities (i.e. some ridiculous upper boundary like 9999999).  Otherwise a subquery would work with the same WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Prices.Price
FROM Prices
WHERE (Prices.MinQuantity <= Invoice.Quantity) AND 
(Prices.MaxQuantity >= Invoice.Quantity)
```

As Gustav and V-ball point out there are many ways to set this up depending on your needs.